# "File corrupt" errno?

Tags: c, posix, errno

Is there a conventional `errno` code to indicate that the specified file is corrupt (it does not conform to the file format it should be)?

I am writing a file parser and don't know what the most appropriate code to return is. There's always `EINVAL`, though I was hoping for something more specific than that, since that would be used for any other invalid parameter as well, and especially in my case it's of value for the caller to know that the call failed because the file was corrupt.

`EBADF`, `EDOM`, `EILSEQ`, `EIO`, `ENOSTR`, `EPROTO` are the ones I saw that could by some stretch of the imagination be used for such a meaning, but is there a convention for this case?

Comment: Are you writing kernel code, or is this userland/application/library code?

Comment: Userland library code.

Comment: No, not really.  You'll just read garbage data.  If you are lucky then you get EOF before you read all the data, no guarantee.  Machines are too reliable today to worry much about this, a disk drive use a CRC check on the data it reads to detect corruption.  Bad format assumptions tend to be solved with a file header that states the format version.

Comment: @HansPassant I think OP is asking about what error code to return, not what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, POSIX (and UNIX before it) imposes no format for a file, so it's difficult to signal a failure in format.  A file is simply a sequence of bytes, where any byte can follow to the previous one in the file.  No record boundaries or sizes have to be specified on reading, so How can we identify tha a file is not format conformant?

Errno values are for identifying system errors (errors produced as a consequence of some condition in the system when issuing a system call) so no `ESOMETHING` constant for bad format.

By the way, the list of numbers that conform the values for the `errno` variable is system specific, and is subject to change from version to version of kernel/stdlib... so you cannot select a number and be sure that the number you selected will not be used by the system in a future version.

For this reason, it is bad practice to use `errno` to return error codes.  Many libraries follow the same pattern as stdlib, but with a prefixed `something_errno` variable.  This is my recomendation for you.

Anyway, a parser normally returns return a parse tree (syntactic tree) and you can use node fields to indicate parsing errors anyway.  Don't pollute the meanings of the system errors using them for nothing but what they were designed for.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be `EBADMSG` followed by `EPROTO` and finally `EINVAL` as a last generic resort.

Some related discussion is here: https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/issues/156

Answer (score 0):

> `errno` code to indicate that the specified file [...] does not conform to the file format it should be

What about `EFTYPE`?

Being picky one could argue this code is for the "opposite" case:

From [the related POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_03):

> This error code was proposed in earlier proposals as "Inappropriate operation for file type", meaning that the operation requested is not appropriate for the file specified in the function call.

But well ...

Answer (score 0):

Setting `errno` in your library code may be a bad idea unless you can guarantee that the OS functions you call cannot set `errno` to the same value. Otherwise you cannot differentiate between errors in your library or errors in OS functions called by your library.

I prefer to define my own set of error codes for my libraries, and reserve one error code to signal an OS error. Like this:

```
enum mylib_err
{
   MYLIB_ERR_NO_ERROR = 0,
   MYLIB_ERR_ERRNO, /* Check errno for further info */
   MYLIB_ERR_PARSE_ERROR,
   MYLIB_ERR_PLANETS_WRONGLY_ALIGNED,
   ... etc..
};

...

enum mylib_err err = mylib_parse_file(....);
if (err)
{
   if (err == MYLIB_ERR_ERRNO)
     error(EXIT_FAILUER, errno, "xxxx");
   else
     .. some other error handling
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my personal opinion, you should NOT rely on returning one of the system error codes, but give the proper diagnostic, with easy to decipher explanation about the problem you face and the possible ways the user of your software can fix.

It's 2018 already, we can throw exceptions and return strings, not 8-bit ints.

Here are the contemporary ["MISRA C++:2008 Guidelines for the use of the C++ language in critical systems"](http://frey.notk.org/books/MISRA-Cpp-2008.pdf), read them, use them. Using `errno` is **forbidden** (see Rule 19-3-1).

Comment: C does not know exception. "strings" typically are not language agnostic.

Comment: OP is asking about C, not C++.